# Navigation controller subview's property is not updating

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITableView, and when I push the view using this code (simplified 'dic' exists). The first time it it will load the markup object. But then when I go back and open a different cell, it uses the same markup object. Should I use a selector on the back button to nullify the `self.ViewController`.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{            
        if (!self.ViewController) {
            self.ViewController = [[TextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil markup:[dic objectForKey:@"text"]];
        }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.ViewController animated:YES];

}
```

The property won't update. I tried different setting methods just to be sure.

Is there an ultra-weak setting I can put the markup Property on?

Comment: Is it part of a navigation controller, or being presented in a modal view?

Comment: NavigationController will be updated with the new viewControler only if u use pushViewController, if you are using the presentModalViewController it wont be updated.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that, line. No, it won't update with pushViewController.

Comment: Hey I'm really sorry, I forgot to add in a good part of that question. It's all there now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I simply nullified the self.ViewController if it already existed. I used this at the beginning of the code.

```
if (self.ViewController) {
    self.ViewController = nil;
}
```